# JetBrains toolbox couldn't recognize the android Studio already installed in my PC and its version

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-toolbox

I installed JetBrains toolbox in-order to auto update the Android Studio as instructed by the Studio itself. After installation of JetBrains toolbox, I found that JetBrains toolbox couldn't find the Android Studio which is installed on the PC and asked me to redownload it via the toolbar itself. After I redownloaded the Studios, I found that even if I updated the app lets say (Chipmunk --> Dolphin) the toolbox couldn't find it and try to update the Studio Again. Anyone facing similar issue in newer versions of Android Studio and Jetbrain Toolbox ?

[image: Image of Android Studio after Dolphin update and the Toolbox re downloading it]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android studio dolphin. I did not install toolbox plugin. It works fine. When I checked for updates it works correctly (says, I already have updated version). I suggest you to delete that plugin unless you use for its intended purpose. (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7200-android-toolbox-plugin)

Comment: Seems like there's a misunderstanding here. The question is about the Jetbrains Toolbox application, which is an installer and application manager for Jetbrains IDEs, and in this case is not accurately recognizing the presence of the Android Studio IDE. Android Toolbox is an outdated plugin for IntelliJ and Android Studio, and is not related to the original question.